# Generate warning for resource without description resx

Tags: c#, resharper, resx

I would like to know is there any way to make compiler/resharper warning for the resources that has no description in resx file? In order to standardize resource documentation.

EDITED:
I want to see the error in IDE.

Thank You!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own msbuild [task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716), which will check for file existence.